# Java HW, string initialized error

Tags: java

Below is my Homework that I am having a problem with. I realize the string `piglatin` is not initialized, but I am not sure how to set a variable to it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PigLatinHomework {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type in a word: ");
    String en = s.next();
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"; 
    boolean startVowel = false;
    char wordStart = en.charAt(0);
    String piglatin;



    for(int i=0; i<vowels.length(); i++){
      if(vowels.charAt(i) == wordStart){
        piglatin += en + "hay";
        startVowel = true;
      }
    }
    if(startVowel == false){
      piglatin += en.substring(1) + wordStart + "ay";
    }
    System.out.println("Piglatinized: " + piglatin);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `String piglatin = "";` to initialize the variable as an empty string.